# В фильтре поиска Joomla не русифицирован тег COM_CONTENT_tag_FILTER_LABEL

Tags: joomla

[image: Не русифицирован тег фильтра Joomla]

Пробовал добавить строку в файл ru-RU.com_content.ini – не помогло. Как можно исправить такую ошибку?

Answer (score 0):

Не нашел иного решения, кроме как обработать стилями:

```
label.filter-search-lbl {
    display: inline;
    visibility: hidden;
}

label.filter-search-lbl:before {
    content: "Фильтр";
    display: inline;
    visibility: visible;
}
```